# doctrine2 - generating entities

Tags: php, doctrine-orm

i'm using doctrine2 cli for generating entities.

i have the original classes defined in PHP with docblock.
when i run the doctrine orm:generate-entities, the new files are created - fields are generate, and methods (setters/getters) are created.

the problem is, i want to copy my own custom methods from the original files (without extending the files).

for example:
i have skel\Employee.php with:

```
class Employee {
    /** comments */
    public $key;
    public function myCustomMethod(){
        ....
    }
}
```

when i run orm:generate-entites, models\Employee.php is created but myCustomMethod() is not copied

is there a way to copy custom commands?

Answer (score 0):

Create your models / entities in code first with annotation mapping then use `orm:schema-tool:create` to create your database schema and if not doing so automatically, `orm:generate-proxies`.

See the note [here](http://www.doctrine-project.org/docs/orm/2.1/en/reference/tools.html#entity-generation)

> If you are however putting much more logic on the entities you should refrain from using the entity-generator and code your entities manually.

Comment: is the proxy file supposed to be loaded? or just the entity file? i'm using code igniter and loading data using $this->em->find('models\Employee', 1);

Comment: Proxies are generated by Doctrine either automatically at run-time (typical for development) or manually. See http://www.doctrine-project.org/docs/orm/2.0/en/reference/configuration.html#auto-generating-proxy-classes-optional. Proxies are invisible to your application (they extend your entities) but in essence are what the entity manager / repository return

Comment: thing is, i want the entities to be auto generated, and i need the custom methods to be copied. now i can see that they are copied into the proxy, but the proxy tries to run parent::myCustomMethod() (parent=the generated entity). it does not contain the method

Comment: Why are you generating entities? The documentation is pretty clear about this